# Jquery Autorefresh not function

Tags: php, jquery

I have an Jquery Auto refresh using in my page. I using 3 function to refresh some page.
For 1 and 2 function working good. But facing the problem when wanted auto refresh in function 3. In that page, I have data got from table database. When running the page, it's not auto refresh.

And here is my jquery function :

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval
(
    function ()
    {
            $('#load_yesterday').load('day/yesterday.php').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#load_today').load('day/today.php').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#load_data').load('datas.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 5000
);
```

and the html div for set auto refresh :

```
<div id="load_yesterday">
<?php include ("day/yesterday.php"); ?>
</div>

<div id="load_today">
<?php include ("day/today.php"); ?>
</div>

<div id="load_data">
<?php include ("datas.php"); ?>
</div>
```

for load yesterday and today working good. But when load data, it's not auto refresh. In data.php, there are not JS code, just get data from table database.

Anyone have suggestions ? Or I got wrong in my code ? Please help.

Comment: you can check console what data is coming from datas.php

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the php pages in the PHP code as you have called them using them in jQuery(code below).

```
setInterval(function (){
            $('#load_yesterday').load('day/yesterday.php').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#load_today').load('day/today.php').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#load_data').load('datas.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: what if user's have an old browser tho or javascript disabled